# Need to click two times on <apex:commandButton> to call action

Tags: apex, visualforce, commandbutton

I have the code below.

**VF :**

```
<apex:form>
        <apex:tabPanel>
            ...
        </apex:tabPanel>

        <apex:commandButton value="mybutton" action="{!save}" style="float: right"/>
</apex:form>
```

**Controller :**

```
public void save() {
        try {
            system.debug('test');
        } catch(Exception e) {
            system.debug('error');
        }
```

When I click the first time on my button, nothing happens. I have no log in the developer console. And if I click a second time on it, I have the log.

Do you know what happens ? Why the first click doesn't call the action ?

Comment: Does your page markup include any `rerender` attributes currently?

Comment: No I don't have any `rerender`. Like Eric supposed it, I added a `rerender` and I could see what was the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add a `rerender="msgs"` to the tag. Then you can also add an `<apex:pageMessages id="msgs">` to the page as well

Comment: Adding a `rerender` show me what was the error. Thank a lot.